# Angular DevExtreme Datagrid : how to get values of a row

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

i have this datagrid , **here is my template** :

```
    <dxo-paging [enabled]="true"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-editing
      mode="row"
      [allowUpdating]="true"
      [allowDeleting]="true"
      [allowAdding]="true">
    </dxo-editing>

    <dxi-column dataField="Cuid" caption="Cuid" [width]="130"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Nom" caption="Nom"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Prenom" caption="Prenom"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column
      dataField="EdoID"
      caption="Edo"
      [width]="125"
      [setCellValue]="preSelectEdo">
      <dxo-lookup
        [dataSource]="edos"
        displayExpr="Code"
        valueExpr="ID">
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>

    <dxi-column
      dataField="ShopID"
      caption="Boutique"
      [width]="125"
      [setCellValue]="preSelectShop">
      <dxo-lookup
        [dataSource]="shops"
        displayExpr="Name"
        valueExpr="ID">
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
  </dx-data-grid>
```

and I want to, get a reference to my datagrid and get a row value within a click button:

in my **component.ts**, I've tried this :

```
export class myComp {
constructor(){}
  @ViewChild(DxDataGridComponent) dataGrid: DxDataGridComponent;

  getValueCell(rowIndex, datafield) {
    this.dataGrid.instance.cellValue(rowIndex, datafield);
  }

  onClickBtn(){
    result = this.getValueCell(1,'Name');
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

as you can see, when clicking: I got a result **'undefined'**; it seems like I haven't got the right reference to the **datagrid**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: `return  this.dataGrid.instance....`?

Comment: @yurzui no , it s not that

Comment: Try with this.dataGrid.instance.getCellElement(rowIndex, dataField)

Comment: @JesusGilbertoValenzuela that seems sto be rendrering the html element and not the value (and it worlks only ) with jquery , in my case i am udenr angular

Comment: Well, then if you want to get the value of the selected row or rows, you can try this.dataGrid.instance.getSelectedRowsData() and that method give you the selected rows and you can parse them.

Comment: For getting grid instance try the next https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Getting_Started/Widget_Basics_-_Angular/Get_a_Widget_Instance/

Answer (score 0):

[try this:](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TreeList/FocusedRow/Angular/Light/)

```
 onFocusedRowChanged(e) {
        var rowData = e.row && e.row.data,
            cellValue,
            assigned;

        if(rowData) {
            cellValue = e.component.cellValue(e.row.rowIndex, "Assigned");
            this.taskEmployees.byKey(cellValue).done((item) => {
                assigned = item.Name;
            });

            this.taskSubject = rowData.Task_Subject;
            this.taskAssigned = assigned;
            this.startDate = new Date(rowData.Task_Start_Date).toLocaleDateString();

            this.taskStatus = rowData.Task_Status;
            this.taskProgress = rowData.Task_Completion ? rowData.Task_Completion + "%" : "";
        }
    }
```